# Pick out the true statements.

Tags: general-topology

> Pick out the true statements.
>
> a. Let $f : \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z^2$ be a bijection. There exists a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$ which extends $f.$
>
> b. Let $D$ denote the closed unit disc in $\mathbb R^2.$ There exists a continuous mapping $f : D-\{(0, 0)\}$$\to \{x\in \mathbb R : |x|\le1\}$ which is onto.
>
> c. Let $D$ denote the closed unit disc in $\mathbb R^2.$ There exists a continuous mapping $f : D-\{(0, 0)\}$$\to\{x\in \mathbb R : |x|>1\}$ which is onto.

My Attempt:

- b. True: $f:D-\{(0,0)\}\to[-1,1]:(x,y)\mapsto x$ is continuous.

What about the rests?

Comment: I need some clue.

Comment: @Sriti From which book have you collected these problems? Some preparation book I am understanding, but which one?

Comment: @Samprity: NBHM PhD Entrance papers.

Comment: Nice I shall also start after a few months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) true: just imagine connecting all the points $f(n)$ to a long (self-intersecting) curve.

b) true: $(x,y)\mapsto x$

c) false: the domain is connected so the image would be connected as well.

Comment: (c) the domain is not compact.

Comment: Oh you're right! I changed the argument for c). 

edit: it was nonsense again sorry ^^

Comment: Replaced 'compact' with 'connected'. Now it should be correct.